# Can't update values of members when constructor is invoked

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I've created two classes, 'Cylinder' and 'random', with 'Cylinder' publicly inherited by 'random'. So I created an object of 'random' and tried to change values of member variables of "Cylinder'. Couldn't get it to work

```
#include "constants.h"
#include<iostream>
class Cylinder{
  public:
    double r,h;
    
  public:
  Cylinder(){
      r = 2.0;
      h = 2.0;
      std::cout<<"\nConstructor Invoked!";
  };
  Cylinder(double radius, double height){
      r= radius;
      h = height;
      std::cout<<"Constructor Invoked!";
  };
   
    void display(){
        std::cout<<"\n"<<"Radius:"<<r<<"\nHeight:"<<h;
    }
    ~Cylinder(){
        std::cout<<"\nDestructor Invoked!";
    }
};

class random : public Cylinder
{
    
    public:
        random() = default;
        random(double r,double h)
        {
           Cylinder(r,h);
        }
        void disp_cy()
        {
            display();
        }
};
```

Main file

```
#include "cylinder.h"
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    random R1(10.0,10.0);
    R1.disp_cy();
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor Invoked!Constructor Invoked!
Destructor Invoked!
Radius:2
Height:2
Destructor Invoked!
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor  - section "delegating constructor"

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using, and how does it describe construction of base classes? It is also surprising that the shown code doesn't crash to bits, as a result of undefined behavior due to `delete`ing something that was never `new`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [delegate to the superclass constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) in the member initializer list for your constructor, not in the body of the constructor itself:

```
random(double r,double h) : Cylinder(r, h) {}
```

As is, the default superclass constructor got invoked implicitly (thus seeing default values on your `random` instance), and the `Cylinder(r, h)` in the body of the constructor just created a brand new `Cylinder` that was immediately thrown away.

Comment: @athulkrishnakr: For the record, you'll want to use the member initializer list uniformly, as often as possible, not just for delegation, but for initializing all the members (e.g. in your `Cylinder` constructor). Assigning in the body of the constructor means the default initialization still takes place, then you do it again to reassign them to their "real values", doubling the work (and creating some exception safety issues if the destructor relies on invariants that are only established in the body of the constructor, and the exception is raised before the invariant is established).

Comment: Similarly, you don't need to write out two different `Cylinder` constructors; the default constructor can just be `Cylinder() : Cylinder(2.0, 2.0) { std::cout<<"\nConstructor Invoked!";  };` (though you should make sure the other constructor is initializing `x` properly).

Answer (score 0):

your code is creating a new cyclinder that has nothing to do with the cylinder in the inheritance tree of random

```
    random(double r,double h)
    {
       **Cylinder(r,h);** << just some random variable 
    }
```

also note that you have UB, the member field x is not initialized in the constructor that takes arguments, but then you delete it